# SOQL Issue Passing In AccountId

Tags: soql, query, account, standardcontroller, id

I believe it is my SOQL query that is giving me an issue. I need to take all of the notes and tasks (from the account that wrote them) and list them back out on the Account Page with a custom VF Page. I feel like what I have written should work, I am getting no error messages, but it is not populating on the page still. My assumption is that you can't filter with the Note's Account's Id. Any ideas on how to pass in the Account's Id so that only the Notes and Tasks from that account will show up?

```
public with sharing class noteandtask_controller 
{
    public List<SObject> tasksAndNotes {get; private set;}
    public List<SObject> t {get;set;}
    public List<SObject> n {get;set;}
    String actId;

public noteandtask_controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
{
    actId = stdController.getId();
    tasksAndNotes = new List<SObject>();
    t = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description, CreatedDate From Task WHERE Id =:actId];
    n = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate From Note WHERE Id =:actId];
    tasksAndNotes.addAll(t);
    tasksAndNotes.addAll(n);

    System.debug('the  t list is: ' + t);
    System.debug('the  n list is: ' + n);
    System.debug('the tasksAndNotes list is: ' + tasksAndNotes);
}
}
```

[image: What It Currently Looks Like]

[image: What It Should Look Like]

Comment: notes are related to account by parentId. try *Select Title From Note WHERE parentId ='accountID'*

Comment: @IlyaLepesh just post that one as an answer! Perhaps along with the SOAP reference. Also worth mentioning `Task.WhatId`. Neither query should ever return any records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_note.htm):

**Note** Represents a note, which is text associated with a custom object or a standard object, such as a Contact, Contract, or Opportunity.

Where Field ParentId is ID of the object associated with the note.

In your case you should modify your query to:

```
n = [Select CreatedById, Title, Body,CreatedDate From Note WHERE ParentId =:actId];
```

**Task** is different but [similar](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm):

WhatId - The WhatId represents nonhuman objects such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. WhatIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhatId is equivalent to the ID of a related object. The label is Related To ID.

```
t = [Select CreatedById, Subject, Description From Task WHERE WhatId =:actId];
```

Comment: Thank you both @IlyaLepesh and @AdrianLarson! I haven't gotten to WhatId's yet. I am going to dig a little more into them and parent Ids, your explanation was great.

Comment: For tasks/activities you might also consider `AccountId` if you want this to match what salesforce returns in the Open Activities and Activity History related list.  Salesforce relates activities for account-centric objects (e.g. contacts) back to their parent account with this field.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [@Ilya](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/30686/ilya-lepesh)'s answer. The `sObjectType` of the `actId` variable is `Account`. If you filter `Id = :actId`, the only table you can *ever* query and get any results for is `Account*`:

```
SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE Id = :actId
```

No `Task` ([schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm)) or `Note` ([schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_note.htm)) will ever have its `Id` equal to the `actId` value. You need to figure out which lookup field will be populated with that value. In this case you will want to use `WhatId` and `ParentId`, respectively.

`*` <sub><sup>Actually, slight technicality but you can also use that filter with AccountHistory.</sup></sub>